# How do I loop through and assoc array that get data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

```
while($report = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                $counter = count($report['Date']);
                for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++)
                {

                    $searchOutput .= "<tr><td name='uname".$i."'>".$report['Username']."</td><td name='utitle".$i."'>".$report['Title']."</td><td name='udesc".$i."'>".$report['Description']."</td><td name='udate".$i."'>".$report['Date']."</td><td><textarea rows='2' cols='30' name='comment".$i."' id='comment'></textarea></td></tr>";
                }
            }

        $searchOutput .= "</table>";
        echo $searchOutput;
        $publish = '<div id="submit" align="center">
            <form name="" id="" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=" Submit Report " />
            </form>
        </div>';
        echo $publish;
```

Hello, I am trying to loop through the value generated from database.
What i want is to add a name to each  generated with values from the database, then after filling the report for the generated data's i will submit to another table where users can view their report.
I have use and try the above code, i couldn't get any result.
I will be glad and grateful, if i could get a result worked out, or any tips to achieve my aim.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output / errors are you getting? Please post.

Comment: remove the foreach loop entirely. you don't need it.

Comment: Where are you shouting in your title?

Comment: show the query you are using?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - that shouldn't be a factor for downvoting?

Comment: @PsyCoder ofc it is. It makes it a bad quality question.

Comment: @NADH The error is that the name attribute that is suppose to loop, can't loop, it just output the same $i = 0;

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - FYI, it can be edited too. I did the needful.

Comment: What is this used for `$value1 = array($value);` and you use `$i` that is not set.

Comment: how can i transfer or insert those data after the report is name into another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$i = 0; 
$searchOutput = '';
while($report = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

    $searchOutput .= "<tr><td name='uname".$i."'>".$report['Username']."</td><td name='utitle".$i."'>".$report['Title']."</td><td name='udesc".$i."'>".$report['Description']."</td><td name='udate".$i."'>".$report['Date']."</td><td><textarea rows='2' cols='30' name='comment".$i."' id='comment'></textarea></td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thats just what i wanted to achieve.

Comment: Just as long as there are no reports named `<b><i><u><tt>important read first</tt></u></i></b>` or worse...

Comment: @jcubic, how can i transfer or insert those data after the report is name into another table?

Comment: @Josiah Don't quite understand if you want different table just create it in the same loop.